# I cannot see web.xml contents where I can code

Tags: java, eclipse, web.xml

My eclipse IDE shows a web.xml file which just has specifications kind of list. I am learning from a udemy course and there the instructor is able to type into this file but I am not able to.

Anybody please help!

Attached are the screenshots

My IDE
[image: My IDE]

My Tutor's IDE
[image: My Tutor's IDE]

Comment: You see two tabs at the bottom. You are in the design tab. Open the source tab instead.

Comment: Your instructor is also using a much older release. They should upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You should click on "source" at the bottom, then you will see the source code.

Comment: You can also "edit" the file using the context menu on the Design tab.